# Any suggestions on how to align negative and positive numbers without using \phantom{-}?

Tags: tables

Does someone of you have any suggestions on how to align negative and positive numbers in the following table without using \phantom{-}?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}



\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    

 \usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{float}

 \setkomafont{caption}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}
 \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

 
 \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
 \setstretch{1.3}

  \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
 
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}     

      
  \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Infit und Outfit Indices für UEBE, SOUE, ERDR, UNZU und UEFO}
    \label{tab:infit-outfit}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \footnotesize{
        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{
                @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% fill the space between columns
                l % one left aligned column
                *{5}{c}
            }
            \toprule
            Item    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{uPCM} \\
            
            \cmidrule{2-6} % \cmidrule{7-11}
            & {outfit MSQ}&{t} & {infit MSQ}& {t} & {p}\\ \toprule 
            \emph{UEBE} &&&&&\\ 
            \addlinespace
            TICS 1&1.55&4.98&1.53& 5.27& <.001\\
            TICS 4&1.07&0.74&1.03& 0.31&.21\\ 
            TICS 17&0.65&-4.28&0.67& -4.20&.99\\
            TICS 27&1.50&4.57& 1.42&4.34&<.001\\ 
            TICS 38&1.74&-3.21& 0.71&-3.70&.99\\
            TICS 44&0.57&-5.51& 0.59&-5.45&.99\\
            TICS 50&0.61&-5.10& 0.62&-5.07&.99\\ 
            TICS 54&0.59& -5.14& 0.59&-5.42&.99\\ 
            \midrule 
            \emph{SOUE} &&&&&\\ 
            \addlinespace
            TICS 7 &1.12&1.34&1.12&1.46&.08\\
            TICS 19 &0.78&-2.58&0.77&-2.82&.99\\
            TICS 28&0.72&-3.42&0.74&-3.21&.99\\ 
            TICS 39 &0.94&-3.83&0.68&-4.28&.99\\
            TICS 49&0.94&-0.60&0.95&-0.52&.71\\ 
            TICS 57 &0.87&-1.50&0.89&-1.34&.93\\ 
            \midrule 
            \emph{ERDR}&&&&&\\  
            \addlinespace
            TICS 8  &0.97&-0.29&0.96&-0.48&.60\\ 
            TICS 12 &1.04&0.48&1.05&0.53&.30\\ 
            TICS 14 &0.83&-2.00&0.84&-1.99&.98\\ 
            TICS 22 &0.90&-1.18&0.86&-1.67&.87\\ 
            TICS 23 &0.71&-3.63&0.68&-4.22&.99\\ 
            TICS 30 &0.95&-0.58&0.96&-0.42&.70\\ 
            TICS 32 &0.84&-1.87&0.88&-1.41&.97\\ 
            TICS 40 &0.86&-1.69&0.84&-2.02&.95\\ 
            TICS 43 &1.12&1.30&1.03&0.40&.09\\ \midrule
            \emph{UNZU} &&&&&\\ 
            \addlinespace
            TICS 5 &0.92&-0.97&0.92&-0.96&.81\\ 
            TICS 10 &0.84&-1.91&0.84&-1.93&.97\\ 
            TICS 13&0.74&-3.14&0.74&-3.23&.99\\
            TICS 21&0.75&-3.14&0.74&-3.23&.99\\
            TICS 37&1.14&1.26&1.13&1.31&.06\\
            TICS 41&1.09&0.95&1.06&0.68&.15\\
            TICS 48&1.01&0.14&0.99&-0.13&.43\\
            TICS 53 &0.67&-4.12&0.69&-3.92&.99\\ \midrule 
            
            \emph{UEFO} &&&&&\\ 
            \addlinespace
            TICS 3 &1.04&0.39&1.01&0.12&.32\\ 
            TICS 20 &0.84&-1.70&0.83&-1.74&.97\\ 
            TICS 24&0.83&-1.83&0.91&-1.00&.98\\
            TICS 35&0.67&-3.98&0.65&-4.08&.99\\
            TICS 47&0.98&-0.20&0.93&-0.86&.56\\
            TICS 55&0.75&-2.85&0.73&-3.14&.99\\ 
            \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular*}
    }
    \scriptsize{
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item Infit und Outfit Indices basieren auf Schätzungen separater eindimensionaler Partial Credit Modelle pro Subskala
        
        \item Der t-Wert in Spalte drei bezieht sich auf den Outfit, der t-Wert in Spalte 5 auf den Infit
        
        \item uPCM: unidimensionales Partial Credit Modell; UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck;
        
        \item UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; UEFO: Überforderung
  \end{tablenotes}}
```

Thank you and all the best,
Lili

Comment: Many fonts have tabular numbers and a figure space the exact width of any digit.  In `fontspec`, you might be able to load the table font with `Numbers=Monospaced` and use the space character `^^^^2007`.

Comment: note `\footnotesize` does not take an argument so `\footnotesize` not `\footnotesize{` normalcy  the extra braces would be harmless but here you will force spurious space after the table, pushing it off centre. as you have white space after `\end{tabular` (same for `\scriptsize`

Comment: the `siunitx` and `dcolumn` packages both provide column types for decimal alignment.  Please edit your example so that it may be run to see the issue and test answers. Positing it without `\begin{document}` and without any definition of commands such as `\toprule`  just makes it harder to answer.

Comment: If all the values in a column have the same number of decimal places shown, simply aligning them to `r` should have the result you desire.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the `S` column type of `siunitx`. I completed your code so that it compiles.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx, array}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

 \usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{float}

 \setkomafont{caption}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}
 \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}


 \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
 \setstretch{1.3}

  \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen

 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Infit und Outfit Indices für UEBE, SOUE, ERDR, UNZU und UEFO}
    \label{tab:infit-outfit}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{
                @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% fill the space between columns
                l % one left aligned column
                *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=-1.2]}S[table-format=0.3,table-space-text-pre=$<{}$]}
                       \toprule
            Item & \multicolumn{5}{c}{uPCM} \\

            \cmidrule{2-6} % \cmidrule{7-11}
            & {outfit MSQ}&{t} & {infit MSQ}& {t} & {p}\\ \toprule
            \emph{UEBE} &&&&&\\
            \addlinespace
            TICS 1&1.55&4.98&1.53& 5.27& {$<{}$}.001\\
            TICS 4&1.07&0.74&1.03& 0.31&.21\\
            TICS 17&0.65&-4.28&0.67& -4.20&.99\\
            TICS 27&1.50&4.57& 1.42&4.34&{$<{}$}.001\\
            TICS 38&1.74&-3.21& 0.71&-3.70&.99\\
            TICS 44&0.57&-5.51& 0.59&-5.45&.99\\
            TICS 50&0.61&-5.10& 0.62&-5.07&.99\\
            TICS 54&0.59& -5.14& 0.59&-5.42&.99\\
            \midrule
            \emph{SOUE} &&&&&\\
            \addlinespace
            TICS 7 &1.12&1.34&1.12&1.46&.08\\
            TICS 19 &0.78&-2.58&0.77&-2.82&.99\\
            TICS 28&0.72&-3.42&0.74&-3.21&.99\\
            TICS 39 &0.94&-3.83&0.68&-4.28&.99\\
            TICS 49&0.94&-0.60&0.95&-0.52&.71\\
            TICS 57 &0.87&-1.50&0.89&-1.34&.93\\
            \midrule
            \emph{ERDR}&&&&&\\
            \addlinespace
            TICS 8 &0.97&-0.29&0.96&-0.48&.60\\
            TICS 12 &1.04&0.48&1.05&0.53&.30\\
            TICS 14 &0.83&-2.00&0.84&-1.99&.98\\
            TICS 22 &0.90&-1.18&0.86&-1.67&.87\\
            TICS 23 &0.71&-3.63&0.68&-4.22&.99\\
            TICS 30 &0.95&-0.58&0.96&-0.42&.70\\
            TICS 32 &0.84&-1.87&0.88&-1.41&.97\\
            TICS 40 &0.86&-1.69&0.84&-2.02&.95\\
            TICS 43 &1.12&1.30&1.03&0.40&.09\\ \midrule
            \emph{UNZU} &&&&&\\
            \addlinespace
            TICS 5 &0.92&-0.97&0.92&-0.96&.81\\
            TICS 10 &0.84&-1.91&0.84&-1.93&.97\\
            TICS 13&0.74&-3.14&0.74&-3.23&.99\\
            TICS 21&0.75&-3.14&0.74&-3.23&.99\\
            TICS 37&1.14&1.26&1.13&1.31&.06\\
            TICS 41&1.09&0.95&1.06&0.68&.15\\
            TICS 48&1.01&0.14&0.99&-0.13&.43\\
            TICS 53 &0.67&-4.12&0.69&-3.92&.99\\ \midrule

            \emph{UEFO} &&&&&\\
            \addlinespace
            TICS 3 &1.04&0.39&1.01&0.12&.32\\
            TICS 20 &0.84&-1.70&0.83&-1.74&.97\\
            TICS 24&0.83&-1.83&0.91&-1.00&.98\\
            TICS 35&0.67&-3.98&0.65&-4.08&.99\\
            TICS 47&0.98&-0.20&0.93&-0.86&.56\\
            TICS 55&0.75&-2.85&0.73&-3.14&.99\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
       \scriptsize
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \item Infit und Outfit Indices basieren auf Schätzungen separater eindimensionaler Partial Credit Modelle pro Subskala

        \item Der t-Wert in Spalte drei bezieht sich auf den Outfit, der t-Wert in Spalte 5 auf den Infit

        \item uPCM: unidimensionales Partial Credit Modell; UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck;

        \item UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; UEFO: Überforderung
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

  \end{document}
```

*Edit* : As pointed by @egreg, using `H` for the placement of this table is not safe: it might overflow in the bottom margin. If you absolutely need to have it inserted at the exact point where you write its code, use `xltabular`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, so it can break across pages, and replace `threeparttable`, which doesn't work with `longtable` with the `ThreePartTable` environment (note it has a slightly different syntax) from `threeparttablex`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard for your answer. I don't know why but this code somehow does not compile. there is no error message but it just wont't compile. Do you know as to why this might be the case?

Comment: Did you try to compile just this code? Or to compile from the command line?

Comment: I’d have expected a comment about not using `[H]` for such a big table.

Comment: @egreg: You're right. For my excuse, it was  a bit late here when I answered, and I focused on the question itself. I'll add it